# how to change parameters from find module on Ansible Playbook

Tags: ansible

From last question, I could make Ansible playbook for finding Dockerfiles and build them seperately.
But now I need to change some docker tags while building docker images.

this is my tree of my workspace

```
shell> tree workspace/
workspace/
└── aa
    ├── 11
    │   └── ubuntu.18.04
    │       └── Dockerfile
    ├── 22
    │   ├── ubuntu.16.04
    │   │   └── Dockerfile
    │   └── ubuntu.20.04
    │       └── Dockerfile
    ├── 33
    │   └── ubuntu.20.04
    │       └── Dockerfile
    └── 44
        └── ubuntu.18.04
            └── Dockerfile
```

and this is my ansible playbook for searching, building images.

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  vars:
     basic_directory: /home/ubuntu/aa/workspace
     basic_filename: specific_name/new/workspace
     version: '1.0'
  tasks:
    - find:
        path: "{{ basic_directory }}"
        recurse: true
        pattern: Dockerfile
      register: result
    - debug:
        msg: >-
          command: docker build -t {{ item|dirname }}:{{ version }} {{ item|dirname }}
      loop: "{{ result.files|map(attribute='path')|list }}"
```

in command "docker build" line, i want to change [basic_directory + parameter] part to [basic_filename+ parameters] .

(the results now occurs with basic_directory+parameters)
e.g)
now this works as

```
docker build -t /home/ubuntu/aa/workspace/aa/11/ubuntu.18.04:1.0 /home/ubuntu/aa/workspace/aa/11/ubuntu.18.04
```

but I want to change this as

```
docker build -t specific_name/new/workspace/aa/11/ubuntu.18.04:1.0 /home/ubuntu/aa/workspace/aa/11/ubuntu.18.04
```

I am not sure where I could change this results from find module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using `regex_replace`

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: >-
      command: docker build -t {{ basic_filename }} {{ item|dirname|regex_replace ('workspace/','') }}:{{ version }} {{ item|dirname }}
      loop: "{{ result.files|map(attribute='path')|list }}"
```

I replaced `workspace/` with an empty string, with the `regex_replace` filter. Then, I added my `basic_filename` part.